# Concurrent Requests with HtmlUnit

Tags: groovy, concurrency, htmlunit, concurrent-programming, gpars

Here's my code:

```
def search = {item->
    def url = "http://localhost:8080/search/"+item
    println 'url='+ url
    page = webClient.getPage(url);
    println 'pageURL=' + page.url
}

GParsPool.withPool(5) {
    searchList.each  {item-> search.callAsync(item) }
}
```

It prints this:

```
url=http://localhost:8080/search/1
url=http://localhost:8080/search/3
url=http://localhost:8080/search/5
url=http://localhost:8080/search/4
url=http://localhost:8080/search/2
pageURL=http://localhost:8080/search/5
pageURL=http://localhost:8080/search/5
pageURL=http://localhost:8080/search/5
pageURL=http://localhost:8080/search/5
url=http://localhost:8080/search/7
url=http://localhost:8080/search/6
pageURL=http://localhost:8080/search/5
url=http://localhost:8080/search/9
url=http://localhost:8080/search/8
url=http://localhost:8080/search/10
pageURL=http://localhost:8080/search/10
pageURL=http://localhost:8080/search/8
pageURL=http://localhost:8080/search/6
pageURL=http://localhost:8080/search/6
pageURL=http://localhost:8080/search/6
```

Why do the pageURLs not match the URLs?  There are multiple requests for item 5 and no requests for item 1.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're using a single web client to go to several pages, concurrently. So you expose yourself to all kinds of race conditions. For example, thread 1 goes to page 1, then thread 2 goes to page 2 than thread 1 prints the current page, and it prints page 2, since thread 2 changed it. Moreover, I don't think a web client is thread safe. Each thread should create and use it own web client.

Comment: Quote from the javadoc of WebClient: *Note: a WebClient instance is not thread safe. It is intended to be used from a single thread.*

Comment: Your page variable is "global". Put a def there. Otherwise you overwrite the same var and end up always with the last one.